# compact symplectic manifolds

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Why there is no compact symplectic submanifold with dimension greater than 2 in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symplectic form on $R^{2n}$ is exact, however the symplectic form on a compact symplectic manifold cannot be exact. Hence no symplectic submanifolds (whether of dim.2 or higher).